# Make striped div with alternating rows of text

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains some text in spans. I want to make the text stripy to achieve something akin to the table's

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: #cccccc;}
```

basically make background in each line different.

```css
    #docIndHeader{
    width: 300px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="docIndHeader" class="doc" >
            <span class="assetType">IndHeader</span>
            <span id="IndHeaderID"><span class="fieldName">ID </span>: 83176322</span>
            <span id="IndHeaderVERSION"><span class="fieldName">VERSION </span>: 20190907:105916:000</span>
            <span id="IndHeaderNAME"><span class="fieldName">NAME </span>: INDEX</span>
            <span id="IndHeaderINDEX_STATUS"><span class="fieldName">INDEX_STATUS </span>: A</span>
            <span id="IndHeaderCODE_PRIMARY"><span class="fieldName">CODE_PRIMARY </span>: T</span>
    </div>
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: What issues are you encountering using the same pseudo classes?

Comment: spans could be on the same line

Comment: You're not describing the problem sufficiently. What do you mean by "spans could be on the same line"? Spans are inline by default. You should provide a [mcve] so that we can actually see the issue.

Comment: I added a picture to show how it appears. I need to sripe each line in different color

Comment: We'll need a [mcve] more than an image

Comment: I added css so you could reproduce.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the question? Why do people down-vote instead of helping?

Comment: You can do it with some javascript that runs after the page loads. Just drop it inline with your HTML at the very bottom and the browser will pick it up after everything is loaded. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
span.line.odd {
  background-color: grey;
}
span.line.even {
  background-color: white;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body >
<div class="stripes">
  <span class="line">Some Text<span>Another span</span></span>
  <span class="line">Some Text<h2>this is a heading in the middle of the span!</h2></span>
  <span class="line">Some Text</span>
  <span class="line">Some Text</span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function stripes() {
 var strblock = document.getElementsByClassName("stripes");
 for(var i = 0; i < strblock.length; i++){
   var lines = strblock[i].getElementsByClassName("line");
   for(var j = 0; j < lines.length; j++){
     if(j%2 == 0){
       lines[j].classList.add("even");
     }
     else {
       lines[j].classList.add("odd");
     }
   }
 }
};
 stripes();
</script>
</body>
```

It will even work with multiple spans in the same line. Just make sure that no other spans in the "stripes" div have the class `line` or it will be counted by the JS snippet. the CSS selectors will filter it out, but the JS will need tweaking to only count the spans.

Comment: When I form the div I don't know the length of the line and I just keep adding them and they will go on a different line as the line fills. It's being populated dynamically from database.

Comment: It should work anyway. Are you using a server to load the page or client code? If you're using a server, it will still work. Just change the page template to include the proper CSS classes so the JS can pick them up and apply the `even` or `odd` classes as needed.

Comment: @RomanGoyenko how are you generating the page? Are you using a server-side code or building the page in the browser after it loads?

Comment: Building in browser. I do a webservice call and I have a templating engine that inserts values in a cycle. I have different document types and each document has Key:Value pairs that I insert. Each key/value can potentially have different CSS applied to it.

Comment: that's fine. Just make sure the browser calls the `stripes();` JS after it's done loading the page and it should be good. Give it a try and report back. I'll edit my answer if I need to.

Comment: But when do I put <span class="line"> ? I don't know the overall length and css for each element is extracted from db too (they could be bigger font size) - so I can't calculate the line length. This is like a paragraph of text and I want to make background of each line different.Text is dynamic and I don't know the length of each line.

Comment: Try [LetteringJS](https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js) plugin. It requires jquery and can style individual lines, words, and letters depending on how you want it. If this doesn't work for you, then I'm afraid there's no good way to do what you want and you may need to restrict your design to match what's capable by modern browsers.